# Thermodynamics - 'Internal irreversibilities' in a fluid (gas) across a shock wave

Tags: thermodynamics, aerodynamics, reversibility, shock-waves

I'm struggling to understand(*in an 'intuitive way'*) how it is possible to have, in a control volume, a stagnation pressure loss(*adiabatic and isentropic slow down to zero velocity*) without a change in the stagnation temperature, **across a normal shock wave over an airfoil - for example**(*considering that is said there's no change in the internal energy / No work done or heat transfer / i.e no change in -molecular- random kinetic energy*).

Regarding the irreversibility of a fast compression or discontinuity, using the piston-cylinder as an example, it's easy to understand that there's viscous dissipation due to the fast compression and -some of the energy- transfered to the gas will increase its temperature without doing work and, if the gas returns to its initial volume, there will be a higher temperature than the initial one(i.e. irreversible and non-isentropic).

So, in my understanding, each compression made by the propagation of the shock wave will be lower than the previous one, due to this 'viscous dissipation' cited above. 
Therefore, the 'air parcel' should have ends with a higher internal energy (temperature) after the passage of the shock wave due to the fact that it keeps some of the energy received(that could not be used to compress the 'subsequent air parcel').

This would lead to the same end result as the 'piston-cylinder' example cited above...
But this does not seems to be the case... considering that is said that the air keeps its stagnation temperature unchanged and loses some of its total pressure after the passage of the wave.
This doesn't make sense to me, what am I missing? Can someone explain what leads to this loss of stagnation pressure of the air, without a change in the stagnation temperature, after the passage of the shock wave?

Comment: I am still trying to find an answer to this question.
Is it such a complicated subject that no one is capable to explain it with a straight forward and relatively short answer?
I found another question that, apparently, looks for the same answer and has never 'really' been answered (Gibbs's equation does not explain the physical phenomenon). [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/256960/why-does-stagnation-pressure-reduce-across-a-normal-shock)
I edited and tried to reformulate the question... so that it would be much appreciated if anyone could give me ANY insight. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The passage of a shock wave is adiabatic, but **not isentropic**, as it's not reversible. As such, the entropy of the gas increases after passage of the shock wave, which allows its pressure to decrease without its temperature increasing.

Comment: Yes, but that is exactly the part that I can't understand or 'visualizate'.
Maybe because I'm stuck with the basic concept that, in order to have a reduction in the stagnation pressure, temperature or density(mass in a fixed volume) must reduce.
Also, I thought that an entropy increase was always product of heat transfer, so... In order to have a non-isentropic process energy must be transfered as heat.
So this is my 'mental block' the fact that the 'entropy increase due to a loss of stagnation pressure' instead of an increase in the temperature(by heat transfer).

Comment: How it is possible and what interactions lead to this final state where the 'air' keeps it's original energy(temperature) but some of its total pressure vanishes?

Comment: @LucasT Do you accept that the process of free expansion increases entropy without increasing temperature? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_expansion

Comment: Yes and I see your point. But when we look at this case we are comparing a certain mass of gas that was previously compressed and then expands freely. 
In this expansion, because it didn't perform any work, the internal energy stays unchanged(and temperature), and it became less dense. This allows the stagnation pressure to reduce while maintaining the same temperature.
The increase in entropy is due to the fact that energy was previously available for work and now it is only available to be transferred as heat. Am I right!?

Comment: But when we compare the two control volumes, upstream and downstream of the shock wave(discontinuity), in a real situation, the only way that I can visualize where it is possible to have a stagnation pressure reduction while maintaining the temperature(considering that there's a dissipation of 'wave energy' to the gas at each compression) is if the gas expands beyond its original volume and, since there will be some work(expansion does not occur in vacuum), [...]

Comment: [...] the energy that would be lost in this larger expansion is compensated by the energy gained due to the viscous dissipation, allowing the gas to become less dense and with the same temperature.
This would lead to the situation where the control volume behind the shock wave is less dense than the control volume ahead of the wave.
Is this what happens or I'm overthinking and I'm completely wrong?